# Norton 360 - Scanning thumbdrives

Tags: norton-360

Norton 360 has two main scan options: Quick Scan or Full Scan. Do either of these scan thumbdrives or external hard drives? I know it is possible to scan the external drives by choosing custom scan, but I do not want to have to do that every time.

Answer (score 1):

It took me a few seconds at most to locate these two threads on the Symantec forum:

- [External hard drives scanned during Full System Scans?](http://community.norton.com/t5/Norton-360/external-hard-drives-scanned-during-Full-System-Scans/td-p/609694)
- [Does Norton 360 scan all my disks](http://community.norton.com/t5/Norton-360/Does-Norton-360-scan-all-my-disks/td-p/59934)

Clearly the answer is *Yes*, a full scan does scan external drives as well.